# doctrine2 + symfony2 : multiple $images on same entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

in my database, i got this

```
table data
----------
id
name
description
image1
image2
image3
key
...
```

and my entity Media from SonataMediaBundle, i want to put the images in the entity Media Manager of SonataMediaBundle

How in my entity write the properties for images ?

What kind of realtion is ?

thx for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply 3 times a `ManyToOne` relation to (probably) an `Image` entity.
The entity would look like following:

```
class Item
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="YourNamespace\Entity\Image")
     */
    protected $image1;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="YourNamespace\Entity\Image")
     */
    protected $image2;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="YourNamespace\Entity\Image")
     */
    protected $image3;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $key;

    // ...
}
```